# Get number of pages in pisa (python) pdf

Tags: python, pdf, pisa

Is there a way I can write the number of pages using pisa.CreatePDF?

Here's what I have in my html:

```
td style="width:200px;">Page <pdf:pagenumber> of X</td>
```

Is there a way to get what X is?

Answer (score 2):

```
<td style="width:200px;">
    Page
    <pdf:pagenumber>
    of
    <pdf:pagecount>
</td>
```